# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Poker Stack Exchange](http://poker.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://poker.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 6 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Does the buy-in for a tourney affect the taxes of your winning?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/does-the-buy-in-for-a-tourney-affect-the-taxes-of-your-winning)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What are the overall odds of winning a heads up, texas hold em hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1560/what-are-the-overall-odds-of-winning-a-heads-up-texas-hold-em-hand)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to calculate the odds of the same thing happening both times I have a specific hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/how-to-calculate-the-odds-of-the-same-thing-happening-both-times-i-have-a-specif)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Texas Hold 'Em possibilities](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/texas-hold-em-possibilities)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Rank of two-pair hands for low in razz or 7-stud hi-low](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1571/rank-of-two-pair-hands-for-low-in-razz-or-7-stud-hi-low)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Playing online poker with Italians (on PokerStars)?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/playing-online-poker-with-italians-on-pokerstars)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---